# powerpoint loop a series of animation

Tags: loops, animation, powerpoint

I am currently working on a slide with an animation of sunrise to sunset as a background.
Then there are some pictures fade in and fade out.

Now, I am having difficult to loop the series of animation that repeat the pictures fade in and fade out until sunset.

I am trying to avoid manual timing setting because the duration from sunrise to sunset is 1 hour and there are only 5 pictures to repeat the fade in and fade out that takes only 10 secs for each picture.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately you're probably done with the animation and presentation already. In the hopes this answer can help future questioners, however, [this blog post](http://blogs.msmvps.com/tohlz/2006/09/10/looping-a-slide-with-multiple-animations/) has a walkthrough of steps that can loop a single slide as a sort of sub-presentation.

> First, click Slide Show > Set Up Show.
>
> Put a checkmark to Loop continuously until 'Esc'.
>
> Click Ok. Now, Click Slide Show > Custom Shows. Click New.
>
> Select the slide you are looping, click Add. Click Ok and Close.
>
> Click on the slide you are looping. Click Slide Show > Slide Transition. Under Advance slide, put a checkmark to Automatically After. This will allow the slide to loop automatically. Do NOT Apply to all slides.
>
> Right click on the thumbnail of the current slide, select Hide Slide.
>
> Now, you will need to insert a new slide just before the slide you are looping. On the new slide, insert an action button. Set the hyperlink to the custom show you have created. Put a checkmark on "Show and Return"

This has worked for me.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Helpful hint: for the hyperlink portion: Cutom Show can be found under the Place In This Document section.

Comment: Great but how you advance to the second slide. My first slide is looping no matter what i press ?

Comment: @Anonymous Press Escape and it should break you out

Comment: still works great in 2022. the hyperlink of the action button should be set to a **custom show** (and not the hidden slide). I missed that part and it took me a while to figure out what it was. thanks